# Can't reach login page in Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I recently installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS .
But when sysetm starts I stuck at a black page .
( You can see the screenshot here : http://llink.ir/5buo )

But I can't enter anything in this page (my login name and password or ...) , The only action that I can do is moving the cursor .

Please tell me how can I fix this problem and enter desktop?

Thank you

Comment: Hit `ctrl` + `alt` + `f7`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like GDM is not starting. Try installing it first:

```
sudo apt install gdm
```

If it is already installed, I would try to active it:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

See if that helps :)

Comment: I did this , but nothing changed ...

Comment: Then I'm not sure :( Maybe if it's a new installation, just try to reinstall an see if something went wrong during install? Remember to check updates during install.

Comment: I just installed today & I didn't see any errors during install . I have to mention that gdm wasn't installed , I installed gdm , is there any additional package that I should install with gdm ?

Comment: Are you using 16.04.1 with all updates? Sounds really strange.

Answer (score 0):

Does your computer have Nvidia hybrid graphics? If so, you might be affected by [bug 1559576](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1559576), mentioned in the [Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuGNOME#Known_Issues).

Comment: My graphic adaptor is Nvidia Geforce 5200 FX , is it hybrid one ? I don't think so , it's too old :) !